# Sort a numpy 2d array by 1st row, maintaining columns

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

In python, I have a numpy array of the form:

```
[4 8 2 0 5]
[3 1 6 8 1]
[2 2 6 0 3]
[9 7 6 7 8]
[5 8 1 1 4]
```

I want to sort it by the value of the first row from left to right in ascending order, while keeping the columns as a whole intact. The actual arrays are of unspecified dimensions, and pretty gigantic, so writing something myself with for loops get prohibitively slow. The result should be:

```
[0 2 4 5 8]
[8 6 3 1 1]
[0 6 2 3 2]
[7 6 9 8 7]
[1 1 5 4 8]
```

I can get a row vector with the column indexes ordered correctly using argsort, but don't know where to go from there on actually building the new array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorting arrays in numpy by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674073/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-row)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Source array:

```
In [215]: a
Out[215]:
array([[4, 8, 2, 0, 5],
       [3, 1, 6, 8, 1],
       [2, 2, 6, 0, 3],
       [9, 7, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 8, 1, 1, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

Using Numpy indexing:

```
In [218]: a[:, a[0].argsort()]
Out[218]:
array([[0, 2, 4, 5, 8],
       [8, 6, 3, 1, 1],
       [0, 6, 2, 3, 2],
       [7, 6, 9, 8, 7],
       [1, 1, 5, 4, 8]], dtype=int64)
```

Using Pandas:

```
In [212]: pd.DataFrame(a).sort_values(0, axis=1).values
Out[212]:
array([[0, 2, 4, 5, 8],
       [8, 6, 3, 1, 1],
       [0, 6, 2, 3, 2],
       [7, 6, 9, 8, 7],
       [1, 1, 5, 4, 8]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Appears to work, but unfortunately this is as part of an assignment that doesn't allow use of additional libraries.

Comment: @JoeGallagher, you can't use Numpy for sorting Numpy arrays??

Comment: No, can't use pandas, my response was made before your edit. Numpy solution works.